# Django queryset contains

Tags: python, django

My code is

```
queryset = Product.objects.filter(category=2)
for i in queryset:
    for j in Windows_system_apps:
        if i.name in j:
            i.app_type = 1
            i.save()

pattern = ["alpha123", "delta1", ... ]
```

For the products model, I have to check if the names of the products contain a pattern, where pattern is of type list.

My question is can I implement above logic using __contains and __in filters?

Comment: `Product.objects.filter(category=2, name__in=pattern).update(app_type=1)` ?

Comment: @floydya pattern is of type list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `name` is a `CharField`, and `Windows_system_apps` is a collection of collections of strings, you can use the [**`__in`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) with:

```
from itertools import chain

Product.objects.filter(category=2, name__in=chain.from_iterable(Windows_system_apps))
```

In case you want to change the `app_type`, and that `app_type` is again a "raw" database field, you can do this in one query like:

```
from itertools import chain

Product.objects.filter(
    category=2, name__in=chain.from_iterable(Windows_system_apps)
).update(app_type=1)
```

This will result in a quwery like:

```
UPDATE product
SET app_type=1
WHERE category=2 AND name IN ("foo", "bar")
```

with `"foo"` and `"bar"` the *hypothetical* elements of the `Windows_system_apps` list.